# jquery data retrieval from php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whenever I use classes and lots of includes with Ajax, my data variable always contains the full HTML of the page and never just the simple response that I echo. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate PHP file that will process your request. That way, only the response data will pass to your ajax.

```
    <?php    
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        if(isset($_POST['add_product'])){
            // Add function goes here
        }
        if(isset($_POST['delete_product'])){

            // Delete function goes here
        }
        if(isset($_POST['update_product'])){

            // Update function goes here
        }
    }else{ die('No Direct Access');}
?>
```

Comment: So is that the standard way with Ajax to create a desperate file for each function? It just seems so messy?

Comment: I just edited my code. I hope that will explain a bit more. In you ajax code just pass post variable e.g delete_product=true so that the processor will know which function will process the request the request.

Comment: OK I see, would the Ajax break if I were to call a method within the code above?

Comment: Nope it wont, your just basically letting the php file know which function should be use. I actually use it like data:'add_product=true' then the php file know that add_product variable isset then the function inside it will be the one to be used